# "Credulous" - Formal Use

Tags: word-choice, phrases, vocabulary

What is the basic meaning of **Credulous** , in which context it will be the best to use instead of "willing to believe" ? How formally we can use **"Credulous"** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Credulous* isn't a terribly common word, but it's not especially formal and can potentially be used in any register. The most important thing is its connotation: it means not just someone who is willing to believe, but implies a negative opinion of the person's intelligence and judgement. In this sense it's a near synonym of *gullible*.

Answer (score 2):

"Willing to believe" is a much more neutral-sounding phrase than "credulous", which is more along the lines of "willing to believe anything (no matter how far-fetched or improbable)".