# What do you call someone who doesn't believe in "ghost"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

What do you call someone who doesn't believe in "ghost" neither in ghost stories ?

web has it's answer as *skeptics* but that's not a dictionary answer. It is more or less conventional.

Comment: In a lot of cases, people would refer to such a person as "normal", while calling people that _do_ believe in ghosts as "superstitious". The only context in which a language would need a word for what you describe would be if that "non-believing" would be something special. As far as I know, in most English-speaking environments, not-believing in ghosts is the norm, and no word for that is needed. So I venture a guess that it does not exist.

Comment: Related question, just in case this seems familiar: [Name for someone who does believe in ghosts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182490/what-do-you-call-someone-who-believes-in-ghosts)

Comment: Do you have a specific word for that in another language?

Comment: @Neeku, if i had I would have gone to google translator instead of stackexchange.

Comment: Well, Google Translator isn't always helpful with slang, expressions and other phrases. This word would directly depend on the culture of the speakers of a language, and I was just curious to know if such a word exists for that in any language, since that topic pops up a lot among Persian people as well as the Turkish ones, but no specific word for it, just "believer in ghost" would be used.

Answer (score 2):

The comment on your question goes part of the way to answering - a person believing in ghosts could be considered superstitious (and it is certainly true that, as a belief that is not generally considered the norm in English-speaking countries, there is no specific descriptor for people who *don't* hold this belief).

If we think around this problem and consider synonyms for superstitious, such as *irrational*, we can then find antonyms for these - such as *rational*. A *rationalist* is someone who bases their beliefs on logic and reason, which would cause them to reject superstition which essentially calls for faith- or emotion-based belief. More on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationality), of course. It's similar to the distinction between a religious believer and an atheist.

On the other hand, another synonym for superstitious is *credulous* (the trait of being gullible and accepting), whose antonyms would include *skeptical* - although if you take that a step further to mean someone who not only rejects superstitions and the like, but also rejects superficial received wisdom or reasoning through distrust of other people's motives, they might be described as *cynics*.